# My coinflip function isnt outputting anything

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

(Ignore the dumb message replies, inside jokes) - I'm wondering why my coinflip doesn't work. I got the first message function to work fine with no problems whatsoever, but the coinflip one isnt working at all. (I've included pretty m uch the full code with censored stuff) This is in VSC using JS, Node, and Discord.js.

```
console.log('gamercum');

const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.login('ODUwMDI5MjUxMzIyNTc2OTI0.YLjxbg.EZBRMra3o8Srs4gBCwLz_1NQgTU');

client.on('ready', readyDiscord);

function readyDiscord() {
    console.log('boolin');
}

function coinFlip() {
    var flip = Math.floor(Math.random());
    if(flip = 1) {
        msg.reply('heads');
    } else {
        msg.reply('tails');
    }
}


client.on('message', gotMessage);

function gotMessage(msg) {
    console.log(msg.content);
    if(msg.content === 'gamercum' || msg.content === 'Gamercum' || msg.content === 'gamer cum' 
|| msg.content === 'Gamer cum') {
        msg.reply('we pimp chimpin');
    }
}

client.on('message', getMessage);

function getMessage(msg) {
   console.log(msg.content);
     if(msg.content === 'coinflip') {
        coinFlip();
     }
 }
```

Comment: I am not too familiar with javascript but you say if (flip = 1) but shouldn't it be if(flip == 1)?

Comment: define "not working"

Answer (score 1):

`var flip = Math.floor(Math.random());` will always give you 0.
You probably want `Math.round(Math.random())`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Musa said, the primary issue is that you are assigning flip in the if statement.

```
if(flip = 1)
```

should be

```
if(flip == 1)
```

here is a repl that has the coinflip function working. I replaced the msg.reply with a console.log for testing.

https://replit.com/@AdrianEdelen/ImpoliteDishonestGraphicslibrary#index.js

Answer (score -2):

There looks like there could be multiple issues here.  In addition to the asssign instead of compare, and the math function, you likely need to pass `msg` from the calling function into `coinFlip`:

```
function coinFlip(msg) {
    var flip = Math.round(Math.random());
    if (flip == 1) {
        msg.reply('heads');
    } else {
        msg.reply('tails');
    }
}

function getMessage(msg) {
    console.log(msg.content);
    if (msg.content === 'coinflip') {
        coinFlip(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you! things are working now. I'm pretty new to coding and I think I might've bitten off more than I can chew here haha.